# Query Results not being displayed please help

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
$args = array(

'post_type' => 'shows',

'operator' => 'AND',

'tax_query' => array(

             array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'location',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'term' => 'california',
                  ),  

             array(    
                  'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'term' => 'comedy',   
                  )
    )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query($args);

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

echo '<li>';
the_title();
echo '</li>';

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

my taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('location',array (
  0 => 'shows',
),array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'location','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'location'),'singular_label' => 'location') );

register_taxonomy('genre',array (
  0 => 'shows',
),array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'genre','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'genre'),'singular_label' => 'genre') );
```

my objective is to display the posts with terms ex. california and comedy, i tried to do the relation but unfortunately no results are displayed

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you only call the title using `the_title` if you want to display the terms of the custom taxonomies you need to call them and the easiest way would be to use [`get_the_term_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) for each taxonomy :

```
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

echo '<li>';
the_title();
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', 'Location: ', ' ', '' );
echo <br/>
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'genre', 'Genre: ', ' ', '' );
echo '</li>';

endwhile;
```

Comment: thanks @Bainternet, but i really want is. I want to show only the posts having terms from location (tax) and genre (tax)..